# Codeigniter active record query count

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

in my project i have 4 tables. One called `Calls`, `Projects`, `Products` and `Users`.

*Calls* has 2 FK (`project_id` and `user_id`) and *Projects* has one FK (`product_id`).

I'm trying to query the table *Calls* and I want to know the amount of calls for each product has been received from each operator.

I'm trying to query something like this:

```
[{"name":"User1","Project1":"120","Project2":"10,"Project3":"140...}
{"name":"User2","Project1":"80","Project2":"60,"Project3":"14...}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing when you mean operator you mean user

```
$this->db->select('count(P.product_id) as total_product ,CL.project_id, CL.user_id, P.project_name')
            ->from('Calls CL')
            ->join('Projects P', 'P.project_id=CL.project_id')
            ->group_by('CL.project_id, CL.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Now your can write a php script to loop through your result to make the json

```
    $index = 0;
    $user_data = array();
    $user_key = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if(!isset($user_key[$row['user_id']])){
            $user_key[$row['user_id']] = $index;
            $index++;
        }
        $user_data[$user_key[$row['user_id']]]['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
        $user_data[$user_key[$row['user_id']]][$row['project_name']] = $row['total_product'];
    }
```

I did not tested the code but it should work

Comment: You just saved me from having a seizure. :)
I would look into but it seems it will do the job! ;)